# Why do some actors in credits appear as - Character (As Actor)

Tags: credits, imdb

I was just browsing IMDb and always wondered why in some movies an actor/actress will appear in the credits as the character but right beside in parenthesis "As Name"? Check out Dane DeHaan's profile as an example:

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2851530/?ref_=tt_cl_t1

There are two in his profile, one for Lincoln - Second White Soldier (as Dane Dehaan) and one for At Risk - Cal Tradd (as Dane Dehaan)

Can anybody provide a reason for this? Or is this an IMDb only tweak?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because there is a difference between how IMDb (or another source) lists the actor's name than their credit in a movie.  The name after 'as' shows how they were credited in the movie.

In the case here, it is because there is a difference in the capitalization between Dane DeHaan and Dane Dehaan. The difference here is relatively minor, they can be more significantly different.

Comment: ahhh, nice. Thank you, that makes sense to me. It's also pretty sad that the movie credits can't even get the names correct.

Comment: @ChadKapatch - It's not always the fault of the credit writers. Some actors operate under different names, and it's not unheard of for actors to change their *screen name* several times in their career.

Comment: Example: Arnold Schwarzenegger was "Arnold Strong" in "Hercules in New York". http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000216/#Actor

Comment: Another example is Laurence Fishburne, who has been credited as "Laurence Fishburne", "Larry Fishburne" and "Laurence Fishburne III".

Answer (score 8):

The two names which are listed are the one the actor is commonly known as and the other is how the credit in the film is given.

(EDIT: So the main listing is the main one and the one in the parenthesis the credited.)