# Why "and" instead of "starring"?

Tags: credits, ncis-los-angeles

[LL Cool J,](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005112/) the rapper, stars in [NCIS:LA](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1378167/) as one of the main characters. However, his name is under "and" in the opening credits. Why is that? Is it because he is also a rapper? I am curious to know.

Comment: Can you find or get a screenshot of the credit card you're talking about?

Comment: Related? See [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16222/why-do-some-closing-credits-show-the-character-name-of-only-one-actor) and [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/in-opening-credits-for-tv-shows-why-does-it-say-with-so-and-so-for-some-actor)

Comment: Credit card? What credit card?

Comment: Credit card, as in the graphic of the credit in the opening credits of the show... It's called a "card"...

Comment: @Catija https://youtu.be/XL2FwGTcHSk?t=72

Comment: @Catija sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: I'm struggling to recall an anecdote about a diva actress who was enraged because they'd forgotten her "and" at the end of the credits. When she rang the producer to complain, he replied that if she carried on complaining, he'd change it to a "but".

Comment: Voting up the duplicate of "What Rules govern..." from @Richard.  I also recommend the Wikipedia Article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Harris) on Jonathan Harris as it explains why he was a "special guest star" for every episode of Lost in Space.  While it's not a direct answer on "and" billing, it kind of illustrates an early use of "last place" in main billing gaining prestige with a special annotation.

Comment: Agreed, it's a dupe.  LL Cool J is listed last in the main credit section.  Generally, well known actors are listed either first or last.

Comment: @Richard can you make your comment an answer ?